# How to detect placeholder shown for a child input consistenty?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I would like to determine when a child input component is showing a placeholder element with useEffect. In order to do so, I created a ref and passed it to the child using the context. I have an effect to check if a placeholder is visible.

```
const FloatingTextField = ({ disabled = false, readOnly = false, plainText = false, id }) => {
  const [placeholderShown, setPlaceholderShown] = useState(false);
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  const isShowingPlaceholder = () => {
    if (inputRef.current) {
       const input = inputRef.current;
       const placeholder = input.getAttribute('placeholder');
       const value = input.value;
       setPlaceholderShown(input && placeholder && !value);
    } else {
       setPlaceholderShown(false);
    }
  };
  useEffect(isShowingPlaceholder, [inputRef])
  
  const value = {
    disabled,
    readOnly,
    plainText,
    placeholderShown,
    id
  };

  return <FloatingTextContext.Provider value={value}>
      <div className="form-floating">{children}</div>
   </FloatingTextContext.Provider>
}
```

The effect only runs once when the component is first mounted. It does not update the value when the input value is updated (for example).